# How to save the input of a Reducer as a file on the Reducer machine and then access it again in the same reduce phase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement decision tree using *mapreduce*. In my reduce phase I want to save the output of my mapper in a `.data` file, and then again access it in the same reducer.

Since I require the data in form of instance for which I require `*.data` file and not the array of string provided by mapper as output.

This is what I am doing right now:

```java
public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)  
    throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    Writer writer = null;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream( key+"/temp.data"), "utf-8")
    );
    for (Text val : values) {
            writer.write( val.toString() + "\n");
    }
}
```